# Can I write a cover group/Cover point on internal variables/registers in a module/Class?

Tags: code-coverage, system-verilog

I am randomly driving some registers within my design(on an internal block) using some variables/registers in my .sv file(TB level) with the help of configuration class and randomize method in a pretty straight forward way.

Now, I am curious, if I could write a cover group on these TB internal registers that are driving random values on the registers inside the design since those are not available as ports to me. Also if this is okay to do, would it yield any functional coverage metric/report?

I could not find any conclusive answers on this anywhere.

Comment: Do you want to write coverage for testbench's internal registers (No need for this)? Or is it the designs internal registers (I assume you can not access these registers by providing addresses)? In case of accessing designs registers, you may want to have hierarchical path for those registers. Creating scenarios in testbench for covering those registers is a preferable way.

Comment: In case you can access those registers by scenarios/addresses, you might want an active monitor and send it to coverage class. The case statement in coverage class shall sample register values.

Comment: I can read from and write into design registers using address but i am writing cover groups on the registers i read into, checking what i have written is what i read and covering the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can **provide addresses** and read from the registers, you can use an **active monitor** or some other component to sample those values.

Whenever monitor samples some transaction on interface, it converts **pin-level transaction** to **high-level abstract class object**. This is to be sent to **coverage class** via some mailbox, port etc.

```
class monitor;
// first get coverage handle from agent/env class
overall_coverage cvr;

task run();
// sample interface signals
tr.addr = intf.addr; // provided by driver
tr.data = intf.data; // provided by DUT
// send to coverage class 
cov.write(tr);
endtask
endclass
```

The coverage class *optionally* **clones** the object and **decodes** register address. Based on register address, a register coverpoint is sampled.

```
// overall coverage class
class overall_coverage;
// dedicated class for register coverage (optional)
reg_coverage reg_cvr;

function void write(transaction tr_ip);
tr.clone(tr_ip); // optional cloning
reg_cvr.addr = tr.addr;
reg_cvr.data = tr.data;
reg_cvr.addr_cg.sample(); // sample whether address itself is covered or not
case(tr.addr)
addr1 : reg_cvr.addr1_data_cg.sample();
addr2 : reg_cvr.addr2_data_cg.sample();
// ...
endcase
// some other stuff...
endfunction
endclass
```

There can be a **dedicated register coverage class** which is used only for register coverage. There can be one covergroup for **covering addresses** and other covergroups for **data in each address**.

Each covergroup can have coverpoint on data value. Since each register might have different reserved bits and read-only/write-only bits. This can be done as follows:

```
class reg_coverage;
covergroup addr_cg();
covwerpoint addr
{
 bins my_addr1 = {addr1}; // various addresses bins
 bins my_addr2 = {addr2};
 // ...
}
endgroup
```

Now write covergroup for data on each register as follows:

```
covergroup addr1_data_cg();
coverpoint data
{
 bins must_bits = {3'b111,3'b110}; // bins on data sampled from particular register
 bins reserved_value = {3'b011,3'b001}; 
 // ...
}
covergroup addr2_data_cg();
coverpoint data
{
 bins exercised_bits = {'b101,'b110}; // bins on data sampled from particular register
 bins reserved_value = {'b000,'b010}; 
 // ...
}
endgroup
endclass
```

There can be alternatives too, like using single coverage class, using `define` macros for reducing code duplication etc. But this was the basic method described here.

Refer to [bitwise coverage](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/bitwise-toggle-coverage-bitvector), [Wildcard bins](http://www.testbench.in/CO_10_WILDCARD_BINS.html), [Functional coverage](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/coverage1.html), [SV-CDV](https://www.synopsys.com/Community/Interoperability/Documents/devforum_pres/2005nov/07_AceVerification_SystemVerilog_Nov2005.pdf) and [SystemVerilog LRM](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/ieee-1800-2012-systemverilog-published/) Chapter 19 for more information.